# how do I stop my grid from going outside its container div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this interactive grid and when I hover over the cell it colors the inside divs background color but its is coloring  past the container its in, how do I get it to only color inside the container? it seems to stop at the containers top and sides but the bottom can be colored downwards the whole page. This is my code

```
***HTML**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
         <title> Claudias Etch-A-Sketch</title>
         <link rel= "stylesheet"  href="style.css">     
    </head>


<body>
    <section class="back">
        <h1>
          <center> Claudia Etch-A-Sketch!</center>
        </h1>
      </section>
      <section>
        <center><div>
          <button class="Black">Black</button>
          <button class="Pink">Pink</button>
          <button class="Clear">Eraser</button>
        </div></center>
      </section>
      <section>
       <center><div id="container"> </div></center>
      </section>
</body>

<script src ="javascript.js"> </script>
</html>

**JAVASCRIPT**

const container = document.getElementById("container");
const btn = document.querySelector('button');


let y = document.querySelectorAll('button');
y.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let choice = button.innerHTML;
    switch (choice) {
      case "Pink":
        random();
        break;
      case "Black":
        blackchange();
        break;
      case "Eraser":
        reset();
        break;
    }
  });
});

var currentMouseoverFunction = function() {};

function blackchange() {
  container.removeEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
  currentMouseoverFunction = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('pink');
    e.target.classList.remove('reset');
    e.target.classList.add('black');
  };
  container.addEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
};

function random() {
  container.removeEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
  currentMouseoverFunction = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('black');
    e.target.classList.remove('reset');
    e.target.classList.add('pink');
  };
  container.addEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
};

function reset() {
  container.removeEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
  currentMouseoverFunction = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('black');
    e.target.classList.remove('pink');
    e.target.classList.add('reset');
  };
  container.addEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
};

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "griditem";
  };
};

makeRows(24, 24);

**CSS**

#container{

  width:500px;
  height:500px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 300px;
  background:#eee;
}

#container div {
 position: center;
 float:left;
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px
} 

.black {
  background: black;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

.reset {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Side note, `<center>` hasn't been valid in 20 years

Comment: Note: the `<center>` tag has been obsolete for many years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div`s in `#container` are floated left with `float:left;` in the CSS. [Float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) takes elements out of the normal layout of the page, so the `#container`'s height doesn't expand with its content. To fix this, remove the explicit `height:500px;` height definition of `#container`, and add a [clear](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) element after the `.griditem` divs inside `#container`.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const btn = document.querySelector('button');


let y = document.querySelectorAll('button');
y.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let choice = button.innerHTML;
    switch (choice) {
      case "Pink":
        random();
        break;
      case "Black":
        blackchange();
        break;
      case "Eraser":
        reset();
        break;
    }
  });
});

var currentMouseoverFunction = function() {};

function blackchange() {
  container.removeEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
  currentMouseoverFunction = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('pink');
    e.target.classList.remove('reset');
    e.target.classList.add('black');
  };
  container.addEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
};

function random() {
  container.removeEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
  currentMouseoverFunction = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('black');
    e.target.classList.remove('reset');
    e.target.classList.add('pink');
  };
  container.addEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
};

function reset() {
  container.removeEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
  currentMouseoverFunction = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('black');
    e.target.classList.remove('pink');
    e.target.classList.add('reset');
  };
  container.addEventListener('mouseover', currentMouseoverFunction);
};

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "griditem";
  };
  let cell = document.createElement("span");
  container.appendChild(cell).style.display = "block";
  cell.style.clear = "both";
};

makeRows(24, 24);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}

#container div {
  position: center;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

.reset {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section class="back">
  <h1>
    <center> Claudia Etch-A-Sketch!</center>
  </h1>
</section>
<section>
  <center>
    <div>
      <button class="Black">Black</button>
      <button class="Pink">Pink</button>
      <button class="Clear">Eraser</button>
    </div>
  </center>
</section>
<section>
  <center>
    <div id="container"> </div>
  </center>
</section>
```

As a side note, your `.griditem` divs are `35px` wide each, so you should make the `#container` `840px` wide if you want this to be a 24x24 square grid.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a little strange in that it uses some outdated solutions.

First, [don't use `<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), it's obsolete. You should keep the appearance (including alignment) of your page inside the CSS.

Second, you don't have to use float (hardly ever). It is a common source of bugs like the one you're experiencing. Instead you could use flexbox, so your container would look like:

```
#container{
 display: flex; /* Puts all children inside a flexbox */
 flex-wrap: wrap; /* And allows the flexbox to span multiple lines */

 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 300px;
 background:#eee;
}
```

Now, for the children, this solution allows them to distort slightly to adjust to the width of the parent:

```
.griditem {
 flex-basis: 35px; /* Set a base width */
 flex: 1; /* Allows it to stretch */

 height: 35px;
}
```

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) will prove to be a very important tool in your toolset. Give it a go!

**Edit: a simpler solution - sorry.**

I'm usually so excited to tell people about flexbox that I sometimes overlook simpler solutions. As I see it, the reason you resorted to `float` is because you added a ton of `div`s and they stacked on top of each other - divs are "blocks" and blocks take up the hole line.

You could just have created them as `span`s, which as "inlines" concatenate one after the other (like letters) and do the line-break naturally. But then setting dimensions for them wouldn't work - they take their width from their content.

The simpler solution by far would be to give the `div`s the rule `display: inline-block`. Now they'd have the right size, would be inline and wrap nicely.

But then you'd find there's a mysterious space separating the lines, which is not margin nor padding. That's actually whitespace between the `div`s. Ugh!

The easiest way to fix *that* is giving the container `font-size: 0` - the space is there, it just doesn't take up... space.

Anyway, the css would look like:

```
#container{
 font-size: 0;

 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 300px;
 background:#eee;
}

.griditem {
 display: inline-block;

 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
}
```

Comment: There are many uses of `float`, and I use it all the time, just not for the use cases that were well known years ago, as you are pointing out. So "hardly ever" is not the phrase I would use as it would scare some people off from using it at all.

Comment: There's usually many ways to achieve a result, and hardly ever you have to use float, meaning hardly ever float is the only solution that would solve the problem. Imo, anyway. It doesn't mean it's never the appropriate solution but, more often than not, float seems to be used when better ones exist.